# GEE: NDVI doesnt loading in linked maps

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I created a small script with 4 linked maps. Each shows a different visualization. `map4` should show the calculated NDVI. But it doesnt work. The viz will not show. Anyone who know where's my mistake?

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-06-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var image = ee.Image(
  dataset.first()
  );

var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

var falseColor = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B12', 'B11', 'B4'],
};

var vegetationHealth = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B8', 'B11', 'B2'],
};

// Create a map for each visualization option.
var map1 = ui.Map()
map1.add(ui.Label('True Color'))
map1.addLayer(dataset.median(), rgbVis, 'RGB')
map1.setControlVisibility(false);

var map2 = ui.Map()
map2.add(ui.Label('False Color (Urban)'))
map2.addLayer(dataset, falseColor, 'False Color (Urban)')
map2.setControlVisibility(false);

var map3 = ui.Map()
map3.add(ui.Label('Healthy Vegetation'))
map3.addLayer(dataset, vegetationHealth, 'Healthy Vegetation')
map3.setControlVisibility(false);

var map4 = ui.Map()
map4.add(ui.Label('NDVI'))
map4.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, 'NDVI')
map4.setControlVisibility(false);

var linker = ui.Map.Linker([map1, map2, map3, map4]);

// Enable zooming on the top-left map.
map1.setControlVisibility({zoomControl: true});

// Show the scale (e.g. '500m') on the bottom-right map.
map3.setControlVisibility({scaleControl: true});

// Create a grid of maps.
var mapGrid = ui.Panel(
    [
      ui.Panel([map1, map2], null, {stretch: 'both'}),
      ui.Panel([map3, map4], null, {stretch: 'both'})
    ],
    ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {stretch: 'both'});

// Center the map at an interesting spot in Greece. All
// other maps will align themselves to this parent map.
map1.setCenter(-9.1695, 38.6917, 12);


/*
 * Add a title and initialize
 */

// Create a title.
var title = ui.Label('Title', {
  stretch: 'horizontal',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: '24px'
});

var desc = ui.Label('Description', {
  stretch: 'horizontal',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  fontSize: '16px'
});

// Add the maps and title to the ui.root.
ui.root.widgets().reset([title, desc, mapGrid]);
ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('vertical'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your issue is this line:

```
var image = ee.Image(
  dataset.first()
);
```

This reduces the Image Collection down to a single Sentinel 2 tile, which could be completely outside your study area on the other side of the world.

If you change it to `var image = dataset.mosaic()` you should be able to see values in map 4. If `.mosaic()` doesn't return satisfying results you can also think about using other reducers like `.mean()`

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot!